# Bloco de Comentários - VSCode

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

Existe algo que possa facilitar a criação de blocos de comentários neste formato:

```
 /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/
```

Bloco utilizado em diversos arquivos do Core do Laravel.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=karyfoundation.comment

Comment: @VirgilioNovic muito obrigado!

Comment: Jovem se a minha resposta resolveu o seu problema, considere marca-la como asseita clicando no `✔`, assim mantemos o site organizado com perguntas aceitas e respondidas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenho duas resposta para vc, a primeira é mais fácil, mas pode não ser exatamente o que vc precisa.

Com o plugin **Laravel Blade Snippets** vc consegue fazer como nessa imagem. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel-blade

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: No Marketplace do VS Code existem outras opções, veja mais no link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=comment&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance

---

**Agora a segunda opção, mas que vai te dar um controle melhor do que vc quer.**

Para isso vc vai criar um Snippet personalizado no Global Snippts conforma na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse arquivo vc vai criar o seu Bloco Personalizado de comentário. E fazer um Atalho que sempre que vc digitar vai aparecer o bloco inteiro de uma vez *(como na imagem do Plugin que citei)*

O seu bloco pode ser dessa forma por exemplo. O atalho para colar o bloco na página é  `"prefix": "coment-laravel",` veja abaixo

```
"Bloco de comentário Laravel": {
    "prefix": "coment-laravel",
    "body": [
        "/*",
        "|--------------------------------------------------------------------------",
        "| ${0:Page Title}Register Controller",
        "|--------------------------------------------------------------------------",
        "|",
        "| ${1:Page Title}This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their",
        "| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to",
        "| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.",
        "|",
        "*/"
    ],
    "description": "Bloco de comentário Laravel"
}
```

A documentação oficial sobre como usar os Snippets do VS Code vc encontra aqui: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: Gratidão Hugo! Sensacional a criação do snippet, vou criar pra tudo agora! haha

Comment: Muito bom é!! Eu uso muito, pra HTML e CSS, tenho alguns que fazem um template inteiro de Bootstrap por exemplo rss

Comment: Eu usava no Sublime algo assim mas não achei pronto para VSCode, lembro que lá era algo tipo bs3:modal e ele criava o modal com o botão, tudo no esquema.